# Scala to create an array of JSON objects from pyspark dataframe and send Rest API

Tags: python, json, scala, pyspark, solr

I am stuck trying to create a distributed post method for writing an array of json objects to lucene Solr which we have created an API for that sends it in a very specific format [Array of Json objects].

If I have an example dataframe as:

df

```
id | name | age | email
1  | martin | 32 | martin@mail.com
2  | stacey | 45 | stacey@mail.com
3  | kyle   | 37 | null
4  | big ed | 40 | biged@mail.com
```

I would convert the above to a KV json object based upon the headers:
[{id:1, name:martin,  age:32,  email: martin@mail.com },{id:2, name: stacey,  age:45,  email: stacey@mail.com }]...

I have been having some issues trying to figure out the best way to implement this in scala, I have been able to create this in python where I pull each row, convert to json and then I write to solr:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def jsonfns (df):
  import pandas as pd
  return df.assign (to_be_replaced = df.iloc[:, 0:-1].apply(lambda x: getattr(x, 'to_json')(), axis=1))
df = df.groupBy("id").apply(jsonfns)

def jsonlist2(df):
  jsonlist2 = df.toPandas()["to_be_replaced"].tolist()
  final = list()
  for object in jsonlist2:
    final.append(json.loads(object))
  return final

final = list(map(lambda x : x, jsonlist2(df)))

def mlUpdate(b):
  endpoint = {
    "Url": "http:8983/solr/collectionName/update",
       "Body": {
        "add": b
       }}
  return endpoint

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n] 

n = 10
x = list(divide_chunks(final, n))
y = [val for sublist in x for val in sublist]

r = requests.post(url = STGMashery, json = mlUpdate(y), headers = STGheaders)
data = r.json()
data
```

For the obvious reason that this collects all records to the driver node, when processing large volumes of data, this will not work and I have been trying to best figure out how to re-create this in scala.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpOptions}
import scala.collection.immutable.List

dataframe_json.foreachPartition(iterator => {     
val STGMashery = "https:url_hidden"
val STGapi_key = "123key"

case class fields(pId: String, country: String)
case class body(add: Array[Any])
case class param(Url: String, Body: body)

val gson = new Gson()

val t= gson.toJson(df_json.limit(1))


val p = param("http:8983/solr/collectionName/update", body(Array(t)))
val prm = gson.toJson(p)

println(prm)

val result = Http(STGMashery).postData(prm)
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.header("api_key", STGapi_key).option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000)).asString
println(result)
```

This isn't working and it seems like there are likely a few things wrong:

I may not be invoking the correct way to send the data in an array of json objects as required by our api to write to solr.

Any help on what I maybe doing wrong?

Ultimately I am trying to distribute the workload to process larger files quickly by reading in a dataframe and convert to array of JSON and send through our API to ultimately write to solr.